# How to animate popup window opened with window.open() from bottom to top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

Is there a way to animate a popup window opened with window.open() such that it opens from bottom to top in an animated way using CSS animations or through JavaScript.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No there isn't, this is controlled by the browser and/or the OS.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Bottom to top, as in from the bottom of the screen? Or do you mean animating from just a few pixels below the final height?

Comment: You may find [this article useful](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/open-animated-popup-windows-using-javascript/)... at the end you get [this](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/vf4jto0d/2/) - not perfect, but nice to start with.